# cannot convert an argument 1 from 'LPCSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: compiler-errors

im trying to create a imgui menu but occurs a error C2664.

```
void gui::DestroyHWindow() noexcept
{
    DestroyWindow(window);
    UnregisterClass(windowClass.lpszClassName, windowClass.hInstance);
}
```

and this error appears.

'BOOL UnregisterClassW(LPCWSTR,HINSTANCE)': Cannot convert an argument 1 from 'LPCSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'

my knowledge isnt too much, idk what to do